# Value changes when using mov from di register to a variable

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I have a problem in my code.

I'm trying to move the value of the `DI` register to a variable called *var*.
The value that goes in the `DI` register can be either 0, 1, 2, or 3 (chosen randomly), but then when I move it to *var* the value changes to 514 (I used the watch function in the debugger to see that).
The problem is in row 440 under the "game" label.

```
    IDEAL
    MODEL small
    STACK 100h
    DATASEG
    x dw 80
    y dw 64
    green db 2
    red db 4
    yellow db 14
    blue db 1
    white db 15
    arr dw 11 dup(4)
    Clock equ es:6Ch
    hold db 0
    key db 0
    marker dw 0
    var dw ?
    CODESEG
    proc YellowP
        mov[x], 80
        mov[y], 64
        yLoop:
            mov bh,0h
            mov cx,[x]
            mov dx,[y]
            mov al,[yellow]
            mov ah,0ch
            int 10h
            inc [x]
            cmp cx, 112
            jl yLoop    
        ySquare:
            mov bh, 0h
            inc [y]
            mov [x], 80
            cmp dx, 96
            jl yLoop
        ret 
        endp YellowP
    proc BlueP
        mov[x], 113
        mov[y], 64      
        bLoop:
            mov bh, 0h
            mov cx, [x]
            mov dx, [y]
            mov al, [blue]
            mov ah, 0ch
            int 10h
            inc [x]
            cmp cx, 144
            jl bLoop    
        bSquare:
            mov bh, 0h
            inc [y]
            mov [x], 113
            cmp dx, 96
            jl bLoop
        ret
        endp BlueP
    proc GreenP
        mov[x],80
        mov[y],32   
        gLoop:
            mov bh, 0h
            mov cx, [x]
            mov dx, [y]
            mov al, [green]
            mov ah, 0ch
            int 10h
            inc [x]
            cmp cx, 112
            jl gLoop    
        gSquare:
            mov bh, 0h
            inc [y]
            mov [x], 80
            cmp dx, 64
            jl gLoop
        ret
        endp GreenP
    proc RedP
        mov[x],112
        mov[y],32
        rLoop:
            mov bh, 0h
            mov cx, [x]
            mov dx, [y]
            mov al, [red]
            mov ah, 0ch
            int 10h
            inc [x]
            cmp cx, 144
            jl rLoop    
        rSquare:
            mov bh, 0h
            inc [y]
            mov [x], 112
            cmp dx, 64
            jl rLoop
        ret
        endp RedP
    ;===============================================================
    ;===============================================================
    proc Random
        RND:
            mov ax, 40h
            mov es, ax
            mov ax, [es:6Ch]
            and al, 00000011b
            xor ah, ah
            mov di, ax
            cmp al, 0
            je GreenPress
            cmp al, 1
            je RedPress
            cmp al, 2
            je YellowPress
            jg BlueMid  
        GreenPress:
            mov[x],80
            mov[y],32
            g2Loop:
                mov bh, 0h
                mov cx, [x]
                mov dx, [y]
                mov al, [white]
                mov ah, 0ch
                int 10h
                inc [x]
                cmp cx, 112
                jl g2Loop   
            g2Square:
                mov bh, 0h
                inc [y]
                mov [x], 80
                cmp dx, 64
                jl g2Loop
        ret
        RedPress:
            mov[x],112
            mov[y],32
            r2Loop:
                mov bh, 0h
                mov cx, [x]
                mov dx, [y]
                mov al, [white]
                mov ah, 0ch
                int 10h
                inc [x]
                cmp cx, 144
                jl r2Loop   
            r2Square:
                mov bh, 0h
                inc [y]
                mov [x], 112
                cmp dx, 64
                jl r2Loop
        ret
        BlueMid:
            jmp BluePress
        YellowPress:
            mov[x], 80
            mov[y], 64
            y2Loop:
                mov bh,0h
                mov cx,[x]
                mov dx,[y]
                mov al,[white]
                mov ah,0ch
                int 10h
                inc [x]
                cmp cx, 112
                jl y2Loop   
            y2Square:
                mov bh, 0h
                inc [y]
                mov [x], 80
                cmp dx, 96
                jl y2Loop
        ret     
        BluePress:
            mov[x], 113
            mov[y], 64
            b2Loop:
                mov bh, 0h
                mov cx, [x]
                mov dx, [y]
                mov al, [white]
                mov ah, 0ch
                int 10h
                inc [x]
                cmp cx, 144
                jl b2Loop   
            b2Square:
                mov bh, 0h
                inc [y]
                mov [x], 113
                cmp dx, 96
                jl b2Loop
        ret
        endp Random
    proc second
        mov ax, 40h
        mov es, ax
        mov ax, [Clock]
        FirstTick:
        cmp ax, [Clock]
        je FirstTick
        mov cx, 9
        DelayLoop:
            mov ax, [Clock]
        Tick:
        cmp ax, [Clock]
        je Tick
        loop DelayLoop
        ret
        endp second
    ;===============================================================
    ;===============================================================
    proc Gpress
            mov[x],80
            mov[y],32
            g3Loop:
                mov bh, 0h
                mov cx, [x]
                mov dx, [y]
                mov al, [white]
                mov ah, 0ch
                int 10h
                inc [x]
                cmp cx, 112
                jl g3Loop   
            g3Square:
                mov bh, 0h
                inc [y]
                mov [x], 80
                cmp dx, 64
                jl g3Loop
            ret
            endp Gpress
    proc Rpress
        mov[x],112
        mov[y],32
        r3Loop:
            mov bh, 0h
            mov cx, [x]
            mov dx, [y]
            mov al, [white]
            mov ah, 0ch
            int 10h
            inc [x]
            cmp cx, 144
            jl r3Loop   
        r3Square:
            mov bh, 0h
            inc [y]
            mov [x], 112
            cmp dx, 64
            jl r3Loop
        ret
        endp Rpress
    proc Ypress
        mov[x], 80
        mov[y], 64
        y3Loop:
            mov bh,0h
            mov cx,[x]
            mov dx,[y]
            mov al,[white]
            mov ah,0ch
            int 10h
            inc [x]
            cmp cx, 112
            jl y3Loop   
        y3Square:
            mov bh, 0h
            inc [y]
            mov [x], 80
            cmp dx, 96
            jl y3Loop   
        ret
        endp Ypress
    proc Bpress
        mov[x], 113
        mov[y], 64
        b3Loop:
            mov bh, 0h
            mov cx, [x]
            mov dx, [y]
            mov al, [white]
            mov ah, 0ch
            int 10h
            inc [x]
            cmp cx, 144
            jl b3Loop   
        b3Square:
            mov bh, 0h
            inc [y]
            mov [x], 113
            cmp dx, 96
            jl b3Loop
        ret
        endp Bpress
    proc RNDsquare
        call second
        call random
        call second
        cmp di, 0
        je aG
        cmp di, 1
        je aR
        cmp di, 2
        je aY
        jg aB
        aG:
            call GreenP
            jmp endproc
        aR:
            call RedP
            jmp endproc
        aY:
            call YellowP
            jmp endproc
        aB:
            call BlueP
            jmp endproc
        endproc:
            ret
            endp RNDsquare
    proc CheckArr
        mov si, 0
        check:
            cmp [arr + si], 0
            je tempo1
            cmp [arr + si], 1
            je tempo2
            cmp [arr + si], 2
            je tempo3
            cmp [arr + si], 3
            je tempo4
            jg tempo
            tempo1:
                call second
                call Gpress
                call second
                call GreenP
                inc si
                jmp check
            tempo2:
                call second
                call Rpress
                call second
                call RedP
                inc si
                jmp check
            tempo3:
                call second
                call Ypress
                call second
                call YellowP
                inc si
                jmp check
            tempo4:
                call second
                call Bpress
                call second
                call BlueP
                inc si
                jmp check
            tempo:
                mov si, 0
                ret
                endp CheckArr
    ;===============================================================
    ;===============================================================                            
    start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax  
    ; Graphic mode
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h
    call YellowP
    call GreenP
    call BlueP
    call RedP   
    call RNDsquare
    mov [arr + 0], di
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    mov [key], al
    cmp di, 0
    je temp1
    cmp di, 1
    je temp2
    cmp di, 2
    je temp3
    jg temp4
    temp1:
        cmp [key], 113
        jne nextmid
        call Gpress
        call second
        call GreenP
        je prog
    temp2:
        cmp [key], 119
        jne nextmid
        call Rpress
        call second
        call RedP
        je prog
    temp3:
        cmp [key], 97
        jne nextmid
        call Ypress
        call second
        call YellowP
        je prog
    temp4:
        cmp [key], 115
        jne nextmid
        call Bpress
        call second
        call BlueP
        je prog
    ;=========================================after round 1
    nextmid:
        jmp next
    prog:
        call CheckArr
        cmp [arr + 12], 4
        jne nextmid2
        inc [marker]
        mov si, [marker]
        call RNDsquare
        mov [arr + si], di
        mov si, 0
    game:
        mov di, [arr + si]
        mov [var], di
        cmp [var], 0
        je game0
        cmp [var], 1
        je game1
        cmp [var], 2
        je game2
        cmp [var], 3
        je game3
        jmp prog
        game0:
            mov ah, 1
            int 21h
            cmp al, 113
            jne next
            call Gpress
            call second
            call GreenP
            inc si
            jmp game
        game1:
            mov ah, 1
            int 21h
            cmp al, 119
            jne next
            call Rpress
            call second
            call RedP
            inc si
            jmp game
    nextmid2:
        jmp next
        game2:
            mov ah, 1
            int 21h
            cmp al, 97
            jne next
            call Ypress
            call second
            call YellowP
            inc si
            jmp game
        game3:
            mov ah, 1
            int 21h
            cmp al, 115
            jne next
            call Bpress
            call second
            call BlueP
            inc si
            jmp game
    next:
        ; Wait for key press
         mov ah,00h
         int 16h
        ; Return to text mode
        mov ah, 0
        mov al, 2
        int 10h
    exit:
        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h
    END start
```

Comment: Presumably you are operating on a byte sized value using word sized instruction. You should really comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I am afraid SO is not a site where you can post 400+ lines of assembly code and expect people to debug your code.. all due respect.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> arr dw 11 dup(4)
> ```

The fundamental problem with your program is that you've defined the array *arr* as **word**, yet you repeatedly iterate over the array as if it contained **bytes**.
Re-defining the array will be best, and will avoid a great number of other modifications. So I suggest a simple solution to be able to keep using the `DI` register:

```
arr db 11 dup(4)
...
game:
    mov di, [arr + si]
    and di, 255      <<<< removes the garbage high byte!
    mov [var], di
```

This way the `mov di, [arr + si]` instruction sadly reads a garbage byte, but the following `and di, 255` just cleans it away. Simple and with minimal effort.

There's one place in your program where you write in the array. Here just writing the `DI` register is no longer an option. You'll have to use a byte-sized register instead:

```
    mov ax, di            ;Temporarily copy to splittable register
    mov [arr + si], al    ;Only write the low byte
    mov si, 0
game:
```

---

I don't think that the array is large enough. At one line you wrote `cmp [arr + 12], 4`. This doesn't make sense! For a word sized array it points somewhere in the middle and for a byte sized array it would point past the array.
The fact that you've initialized the array with the value **4** implies that you'll want to check for the last element in the array. This is at offset 10 in an 11 elements byte sized array.

```
arr db 11 dup(4)
...
prog:
    call CheckArr
    cmp [arr + 10], 4   <<< checks last element!
```

Comment: I've edited your answer. When __writing__ in the array, your neat trick of removing the excess byte through `and di,255` won't avoid problems. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Fifoernik You're right. I missed that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess from quick look below `game:`

```
    mov di, [arr + si]
    mov [var], di
```

`di` is 16b register, so you are fetching **word** (16b) from [arr+si], and you prepared there number of random 0-3 **bytes** (8b) I guess?

`514` is `0x0202`, indeed it look like two byte `2` values.

So you can fix it in various ways, if your `var` is 16b, and `arr` is 8b source, then use:

```
    movzx di, byte [arr + si]  ; fetch only 8b from []
        ; and extend them to 16b with zeroes (zx = zero extended)
        ; (similar instruction movsx extends with sign bit)
    mov [var], di   ; store the converted 0-3 16b value to var
```

---

edit:
Although your `arr dw 11 dup(4)` definitions suggests the arr is meant to be used as 16b array, so the real problem is probably in your random 0-3 generator, storing bytes instead of words. The fix is then not needed under `game` label, but somewhere else (I'm not bothering to search for the arr generator).

Comment: Please note that advicing to use `movzx`/`movsx` on a question tagged [8086] isn't really helping the inexperienced user.